# Cannot find local variable 'point' and cannot detect landmark points

Tags: android, variables, face-detection, dlib

I am using Dlib to detect the face landmark.

**If  I use z3 compact to detect it, I can get the 68 points.**

However, I get **0 point** in other devices like nexus 5x, z5 or one plus two.

## The following is the code that I use to detect the face landmark point.

```
private Runnable landmarkDetection = new Runnable() {

    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stu
        try {
            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(temp);
            canvas.drawBitmap(temp, new Matrix(), null);
            if (mFaceDet == null) {
                mFaceDet = new FaceDet(Constants.getFaceShapeModelPath());
            }
            List<VisionDetRet> faceList = mFaceDet.detect(path);
            if (faceList.size() > 0) {
                for (VisionDetRet ret : faceList) {
                    float width = 1080;
                    // By ratio scale
                    float aspectRatio = originalImg.getWidth() / (float) originalImg.getHeight();
                    float resizeRatio = 1;
                    final int MAX_SIZE = 1;
                    newWidth = 1080;
                    newHeight = 1380;
                    newHeight = Math.round(newWidth / aspectRatio);

                    if (originalImg.getWidth() > MAX_SIZE && originalImg.getHeight() > MAX_SIZE) {
                        originalImg = getResizedBitmap(originalImg, newWidth, newHeight);
                        resizeRatio = (float) originalImg.getWidth() / (float) width;
                        Log.d("resizeRatio ", resizeRatio + "");
                    }

                    ArrayList<Point> landmarks = ret.getFaceLandmarks();
                    int count = 0;
                    for (Point point : landmarks) {
                        float pointX = (point.x * resizeRatio);
                        float pointY = (point.y * resizeRatio);
                            landmark_pt_x.add(pointX);
                            landmark_pt_y.add(pointY);
                        Log.d(TAG, count + " " + pointX + " : " + pointY);
                        count++;

                        drawpoint(pointX, pointY, temp, canvas);
                    }
                    Log.d(TAG + " added landmark", count + "");
                }
            } else {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No face", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            }
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(originalImg);
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
        }
    }
};
```

### I use debug mode in one plus two. It got the following error when it is running

> ArrayList < Point > landmarks = ret.getFaceLandmarks();

[image: screen shot 2017-03-27 at 2 17 36 pm]

Why do I cannot get the variable 'point'? Please give me some helps. Thank you very much.

Comment: Because there is no `point` variable in where you do break (and maybe you could tell us what line is the break of the screenshot).

Comment: I has already put it on the question. Perhaps my question is not clear sorry.

**ArrayList < Point > landmarks = ret.getFaceLandmarks();**

Thank you.

Comment: What is the meaning of no 'point' variable? I am using this library:    https://github.com/tzutalin/dlib-android-app   . I am thinking about this problem for so many times but I still dun know why I get this problem.

Comment: It means there no `point` variable defined when Android studio tries to get the value of `point.x` (because `point`only exists inside the scope of the for loop below). And that's problably not your issue, this message is more like a warning.

Comment: But why can I get the point from z3 compact but I cannot get it from the other phones? This is quite weird.

Comment: Update: It seems like the problem is coming from screen overlay. My friend modify this then he can use the application.